# Access to a Dataset's netCDF4.Dataset

Tags: python-xarray

After I load a netCDF4 file using the `xr.open_dataset` (or `xr.open_mfdataset`) function, is there any way to access the underlying `netCDF4.Dataset` objects of the `xarray.Dataset`?

The problem is that I want to use the [wrf-python](http://wrf-python.rtfd.io/) library, but it only works properly with `netCDF4.Dataset` objects.  And I would prefer only having to touch each file once, i.e., create a `xarray.Dataset` *or* a `netCDF4.Dataset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Python, so of course it's *possible* to pull out this object :

```
In [30]: import xarray

In [31]: xarray.Dataset({'foo': 1}).to_netcdf('foo.nc')

In [32]: ds = xarray.open_dataset('foo.nc')

In [37]: ds._file_obj.ds
Out[37]:
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF4 data model, file format HDF5):
    dimensions(sizes):
    variables(dimensions): int64 foo()
    groups:

In [38]: xarray.__version__
Out[38]: '0.9.1'
```

Do I recommend it? No, this is not a public API, so you should expect it to break without warning in any future release.

I agree that this could be useful, though, so I encourage you to discuss potential APIs on GitHub.